What kind of objects the tangent space contains: operators or curves?
I have no problems with each definition of the tangent space in separate, but when it comes to equivalence it bothers me a lot: what objects does belong to the tangent space?
I can accept that some things have different definitions as far as they describe the same properties of an object. But there is a big part I'm missing about tangent vectors: why the ways it can be applied to a function $f$ differs depending upon definition?
In the case of a linear operator $D$ it's just $Df$, when we consider an equivalence class of curves the expression looks like $Df=d_t(f\circ\gamma)$
I don't struggle with showing the equivalence of these definitions, but facing issues with understanding how it's possible for a space to contain objects differently acting on functions.
Does it mean that we don't actually care about how to use tangent vectors in this context, and we focus on more abstract properties?
Any help will be appreciated
Upd:
The commentator mentioned a post on a similar topic Abstract definition of tangent space, and yes, it is. I'd read it, but didn't find an answer to my question.
The answers seem to touch morphisms between the defined tangent spaces (however, I find it difficult to follow the 2nd due to it abstractness so I'm not sure if it actually does), what I've never put in a doubt, so I'm still confused about members of the tangent space

Just a quick remark: the equivalence between these two concepts fails on infinite-dimensional manifolds, and in that context then it becomes much more important to specify which "type" of tangent space one uses. For more details, see Michor's book "The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis".

You say "it's just $Df$" - what is "just $Df$", in your mind? As written I don't consider this question coherent enough for a concrete answer. If you elaborate on what you mean exactly then I'll answer it to the best of my ability.

@QuaereVerum, I believe, we need the tangent space to apply a tangent vector to some function, so we need the notion of tangent space's action on smooth functions. In the case of the derivatives definition by the notation $Df$ I meant applying operator $D$ straight to a function $f$

"what objects does belong to the tangent space?" -> derivations. I believe I'm not understanding entirely your confusion... Maybe you could elaborate a bit more. Also, this post may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118419/why-are-derivations-useful-for-defining-tangent-vectors/4957616#4957616

@Oscar, when we define the tangent space as the equivalence classes of curves, it members seem to be curves itself, which requires to define a specific way of applying it to a function. Operators $d_t(f\circ \gamma)$ are not included in a such defined tangent space, this is the place when my confusion arises

In the curve view, a tangent vector is equivalence class of curves. When you say how to "apply it" to a function, you are saying which differential operator corresponds to that given equivalence class of curves.

@JackozeeHakkiuz, obviously, but it's about the equivalence of definitions, not a member of the tangent space itself. When we have a curve equivalence class, which we consider a tangent vector, we should have the way of applying it to a functions captured by definition, but in fact we don't have one. We can apply it only if we additionally made up a way to do so

Why do you think "we should have [it] captured by definition"? An equivalence class of curves is not defined as an operator acting on functions, so we need to separately define how it's supposed to act on functions. Is that the question or am I completely missing the point of your comment?

@JackozeeHakkiuz, that's exactly my question: why are different kinds of objects (curves and derivations) included in the tangent space?
If tangent vectors are supposed to act on functions (I believe so), then I don't understand how is it possible to include both curves and derivations in the tangent space.
That's the place where the 2nd question arises: do we care at all how tangent vectors act on functions

Well, it's not like it contains both at the same time. It's just that you have two equivalent representations of a structure. For example, take the sets $X={a,b,c}$ and $Y={1,2,3}$. Since you have a bijection $X\cong Y$, you could consider that one set is equivalent to the other, all that I'm going to care about is that they are sets with three elements. So you could ask, "what is the set with three elements?" and either $X$ or $Y$ are valid answers. But it's not like "the set with three elements" has both letters and numbers as its elements. It's just that both $X$ and $Y$ are... (cont)

(cont) ...valid representations of "the set with tree elements" because both have the same property of having three elements. In the same way, what matters about "the tangent space" is that it encodes the real algebraic derivations of the local ring of functions modulo squares (see the "definition via cotangent spaces" in the wiki). Doesn't matter if you encode it with equivalence classes of curves or with differential operators. Hope this helps.

@JackozeeHakkiuz, in your example only the property of cardinality of a set is important for us. So, as I understood, we don't focus in definition on property of applying a tangent vector to a function. Instead we talk about algebraic structure of the tangent space. Did I get it correct?
